# Redirecting pdf to html

Tags: redirect

Ive taken over a website for my small company, after a person built part of the new site, but did not take the time to think about all aspects.  This one issue is big!!! I need help, please.

Is there a way to redirect a pdf to an html or any other type page?  Here is the problem I'm having.  The old site has a bunch of pdf's for our clients to see price lists for each of our main products.  I have created a PHP for our price lists now.

Here is the URL to the OLD pdf parts list.
http://www.novon.com/PartsSheets/SMX500.pdf.  There are literally 50+ pages. Hence the need to finally go php.

Any example going to any other page would be fine. Goole for all I care. Just a redirect code. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance
Michael

Comment: Please note that this is not a PHP issue.  It's one for your web server.

Comment: FireFox contains PDF.js as a built-in PDF viewer so anyone using Firefox would get the PDF translated into html

Answer (score 1):

### Redirecting all PDF files using a wildcard RegEx

Assuming you're on an Apache web server this should work (using Apache's mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PartsSheets/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$ /some_other_location/$1.php
```

Note that the php file needs to have the same name as the PDF file for this to work.

### Redirecting a single file

If you're redirecting a single file you could use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /PartsSheets
RewriteRule ^/SMX500.pdf$ /some_other_location/$1.php
```

I could not test this though.

Comment: its one file only, better not to use wild cards

Comment: Agreed, I edited the answer accordingly. But I could not verify the RewriteRule to work.